# asp.net c# session logs out after form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, session, dynamic

Okay so I have an issue with my forms.
I have a collection of forms on one page. The active one dynamically changes depending on the option you have selected. However my issue is that whenever a button is pressed in a form it logs out.

I'm not sure if it's resetting the session variables or not. But I also have the following in my `Page Load` method:

```
// Check if the user is logged in
if (!IsPostBack)
    if ((Convert.ToBoolean(Session["Check"]) == false) || Session["Check"] == null)
        Response.Redirect("/Login.aspx");
```

I'm at a complete loss as to why this is happening.

Comment: So...put a breakpoint on the third line and see if it fires?

Comment: you must be getting `Session["Check"]` as null of false.Chceck logic where Session is created. It might be on another page.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check if the user is logged in
object check = Session["Check"];

//acctually, you should probably take out the if !isPostBack.. 
//and always do the check
if (!IsPostBack && check == null || Convert.ToBoolean(check) == true)
{
    Response.Redirect("/Login.aspx");
}
```

First, do the null check first. If you were to write it this way, what is `check`? more specifically check the `type` of `check` in the debugger?